# Python, standalone print meaning

Tags: python

I am confused as to what `print` alone does, let me explain:

```
if <something>:
     for i in x
          print "Hello"
     print
```

what is the point of the last print, does it do anything?

Comment: Why not run the script with and without the `print` and see?

Comment: Are you sure the `print` in the for loop doesn't have a trailing comma? The final print would be used to supply the newline after a set of previous commands that haven't output a newline.

Comment: add a `,` after 'hello' and see what it does

Comment: Note that it's probably better to use `join`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It prints a blank line. For example:

```
print 1
print 2
print
print 3
```

Gives:

> 1
>   2
>
> 3

Comment: @FreshTendrils If my answer solved your problem, click the checkmark next to my answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @FreshTendrils That's for upvoting - accepting the answer can always be done :) The checkmark is to the left of the voting buttons.

Answer (score 2):

It prints new line in python 2.x. In python 3.x it would do nothing.

I suggest using python console to quickly check things like that.

Comment: It is not a syntax error in 3.x, it just doesn't do anything (useful).

Comment: Note that it does nothing because `print` itself is just a reference to a function, not a function call.

Answer (score 2):

It prints a blank line. This is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print):

> A `'\n'` character is written at the end, unless the print statement ends with a comma. This is the only action if the statement contains just the keyword print.

It can be seeing by running your example:

```
if True:
     for i in [1,2,3,4]:
          print "Hello"
     print
```

Outputs:

```
> python test.py
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello

>
```

Notice the blank line before the final prompt.

Answer (score 0):

It allows you to skip a new line in Python 2.

You can try by yourself by opening a Python interpretor:

```
>>> print

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use this block of code as an example:

```py
print("Hello world 1")
print
print
print("Hello world 2")
print()
print()
print("Hello world 3")
```

---

In **Python 3.x** it does nothing because `print()` is a function. Output:

```
Hello world 1
Hello world 2


Hello world 3
```

---

In **Python 2.x** it prints a new line because `print` is a statement. Output:

```
Hello world 1


Hello world 2
()
()
Hello world 3
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html